# Errors in mapping using a stream

Tags: dictionary, java-8, java-stream, counting, collectors

I'm currently having troubles figuring out how to use Java 8 streams.
I'm trying to go from `lista_dottori` (`Map<Integer, Doctor>`) to a new map `patientsPerSp` where to every medical specialization (method `getSpecialization`) I map the number of patients wich have a doctor with this specialization (method `getPatients` in class `Doctor` returns a `List` of that doctor's patients). I can't understand how to use the counting method for this purpose, and I can't seem to find any examples nor explanations for this kind of problems on the internet.

That's what i've written, it does give me error in the counting section:

```
public Collection<String> countPatientsPerSpecialization(){
    patientsPerSp=
            lista_dottori.values().stream()
            .map(Doctor::getSpecialization)
            .collect(groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization, counting(Doctor::getPatients.size())))
            ;
}
```

Comment: Don't describe your classes. Post their code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you want to sum the sizes of patients lists. This can be done by `summingInt()` collector, not `counting()` (which just counts occurences; doctors in this case). Also mapping seems to be unnecessary here. So you cuold write:

```
patientsPerSp = lista_dottori.values().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization, 
                 summingInt(doctor -> doctor.getPatients().size())));
```

Note that the results will be incorrect if several doctors have the same patient (this way it will be counted several times). If it's possible in your case, then it would be probably better to make a set of patients:

```
patientsPerSp = lista_dottori.values().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization, 
                 mapping(Doctor::getPatients(), toSet())));
```

This way you will have a map which maps specialization to the set of patients, so the size of this set will be the count which you want. If you just need the count without set, you can add a final step via `collectingAndThen()`:

```
patientsPerSp = lista_dottori.values().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization, 
                 collectingAndThen(
                     mapping(Doctor::getPatients(), toSet()),
                     Set::size)));
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, it was explained very well. It still gives me a some problem, it always tells me that there is a method undefined for the type Clinic (wich is the name of the Class). In the first one is summingInt and in the second is toSet...Am I forgetting to import something?

Comment: Sorry, but there's nothing about `Clinic` class in your question, so unlikely that I can help you here. If it's still not solved, then it would be better to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem avoiding using the streams. That's the solution I used:

```
public Collection<String> countPatientsPerSpecialization(){

    int numSpec = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> spec = new HashMap<>();

    for(Doctor d : lista_dottori.values()){
        if(!spec.containsKey(d.getSpecialization())){
            spec.put(d.getSpecialization(), d.getPatients().size());
            numSpec++;
        }
        else{ //cioè se la specializzazione c'è già
            spec.replace(d.getSpecialization(), +d.getPatients().size()); 
        }
    }
    patientsPerSp.add(spec.keySet() + ": " + spec.values());
    for(String s : patientsPerSp)
        System.out.println(s);
    return patientsPerSp;
}
```

I couldn't seem to be able to solve it using your solutions, although they were very well exposed, sorry.
Thank you anyway for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<String, Integer> patientsPerSpecialization =
            doctors.values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Doctor::getSpecialization,
                   Collectors.summingInt(Doctor::nberOfAssignedPatients)));
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how your answer is different from the others, and in which way it improves on them.